# How can I paginate data so it can be accessed forward and backwards?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are developing a dashboard web app in which our users will go to consult their published posts on the 'main website', using Firebase (Firestore). It is displayed in a table that is customizable:
• 15 items are displayed per page by default
• It is possible to display up to 45 items per page (15, 25, 35, 45
• Filtering is possible using a search box and other filters properties (such as type of post, status, etc).

As mentioned, we are developing a pagination system so the web page is performant by returning a few items instead of everything at once, and also because this reduces the reads and so we are not charged for data that is not used by the users, except what they want to access to.

I have developed a small React Hook that allows to get a few properties for the database, and which makes it possible to easily get the current state of the data, to fetch them and to go to multiple pages. Here it is:

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
  endBefore,
  getCountFromServer,
  getDocs,
  limit,
  limitToLast,
  query,
  startAfter,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export const useFirestoreFetcher = (firebaseQuery, perPage) => {
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(perPage);

  // Keep track of the data, loading state, and error
  const fbQuery = useRef(firebaseQuery);
  const [numberOfPages, setNumberOfPages] = useState(0);
  const [dataSize, setDataSize] = useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  // Keep track of the query in the ref
  const [lastDoc, setLastDoc] = useState(null);
  const [firstDoc, setFirstDoc] = useState(null);

  const fetch = async (q, ignore = false) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      fbQuery.current = query(q);

      let querySnapshots = await getDocs(fbQuery.current);

      if (!ignore) {
        // Set the last and the first doc for navigation purposes.
        setFirstDoc(querySnapshots.docs[0]);
        setLastDoc(querySnapshots.docs[querySnapshots.docs.length - 1]);

        // Set data
        setData(querySnapshots.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (!ignore) setError(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Getting data");
    let ignore = false;

    // Set page size
    setPageSize(perPage);

    async function getCount() {
      try {
        let count = await getCountFromServer(fbQuery.current);
        if (!ignore) {
          let total = count.data().count;
          setDataSize(total);
          setNumberOfPages(Math.ceil(total / pageSize));
        }
      } catch (error) {
        if (!ignore) setError(error);
      }
    }

    // Get count
    getCount();

    // Get data
    fetch(query(fbQuery.current, limit(perPage)));

    return () => {
      ignore = true;
    };
  }, [perPage]);

  function goForward() {
    if (!lastDoc) {
      setData([]);
      setError("Last doc was null");
      return;
    }

    fetch(query(fbQuery.current, limit(pageSize), startAfter(lastDoc)));
  }

  function goBackward() {
    if (!firstDoc) {
      setData([]);
      setError("First doc was null");
      return;
    }

    console.log(fbQuery.current);
    fetch(query(fbQuery.current, endBefore(firstDoc), limit(pageSize))); // Broken, does not do anything (empty table)
  }

  function goFirst() {
    fetch(query(fbQuery.current, limit(pageSize)));
  }

  function goLast() {
    setData([]);
    setError("TO IMPLEMENT");
  }

  return [
    numberOfPages,
    dataSize,
    data,
    loading,
    error,
    goForward,
    goBackward,
    goFirst,
    goLast,
  ];
};
```

This is how it is then used in my Submissions Page:

```js
  const [
    numberOfPages,
    dataSize,
    data,
    loading,
    error,
    goForward,
    goBackward,
    goFirst,
    goLast,
  ] = useFirestoreFetcher(
    query(collection(db, "posts"), orderBy("id", "asc")),
    pageSize
  );
```

All the properties are easily useable.

Everything works like a charm, but as a comment said in the goBackward() function, when I go back, the table is empty but the `fetch()` function succeeded, which means either the query returned `[]`, or another issue happened.

I have asked ChatGPT for some help, and had as a response that I need to set my orderBy query to `desc`, which I did not try yet because this is not what I want. I would like my query to be customizable, so I do not want to use that.

Any help is appreciated! If anyone has a question, I am around to respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your `goForward` you do:

```
fetch(query(fbQuery.current, limit(pageSize), startAfter(lastDoc)));
```

Say that you are on the second page of results, and it shows:

> 4
> 5
> 6

So `lastDoc` is document `6` here, and if you run `goForward` you get document `7` and further.

Your `goBackward` will need to do something similar, but then the exact opposite. When you run `goBackward` on the above scenario, you need to run this query:

```
fetch(query(fbQuery.current, limitToLast(pageSize), endBefore(firstDoc)));
//
```

Here `firstDoc` is document `4` in the above, and by using `endBefore` and `limitToLast` we get the documents before that one.

So, you'll need to introduce an additional variable `firstDoc` to track the first document on the current results page, and then modify the query as shown here.

I created a minimal repro of pagination here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firestore-v9-pagination, so compare to that if you can't get it working.

Comment: I would love that, unfortunately I do not see any ``startBefore`` query constraint method. The only thing I could see is ``endBefore``, which allows to get all document and end the query just before reaching the provided ``DocumentSnapshot``.

Comment: Woops, that should've been `endBefore` indeed. Fixed the code in my answer now. :)

Comment: Thank you for the little fix, your response is valuable! I tried and unfortunately without success. It is still returning no documents, while I am sure on the first page it is getting the docs correctly. On the second page the first document is called "Test 19", and is the same in ``lastDoc``, however it is still not able to fetch the 15 last documents before this one. An empty array ``[]`` is returned by ``await getDocs(q);``

Comment: It seems very unlikely that `lastDoc` and `firstDoc` are the same. You might want to debug why that is happening.

Comment: My bad. I am talking about ``firstDoc``! It corresponds to the "Test 19" document, but I am still not able to fetch the 15 documents before this one.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on in your code, but the approach I outlined works fine in the repro: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firestore-v9-pagination?file=index.js (check the StackBlitz console or your browser's JavaScript console for the output).

Comment: Thank you! It seemed my query was not right. It seems it is now working perfectly!

Comment: THANKSSSSSSS I WAS RESEARCHING THE ENTIRE INTERNET and you resolved my problem..